# Check if my Activity is in MultiWindowMode or not using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-extension

How to check if my activity is in **MultiWindowMode** or not.

I have used `Myactivity.isInMultiWindowMode()` and `MYactivity.isInPictureInPictureMode()`, but showing error

Do I have to extend something as `MultiWindow` is not recognizing

I have gone through other post regarding multiwindow but no hope

Comment: Can you add the error message please

Comment: i am not able to type isInMultiWindowMode()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that you should precede isInMultiWindowMode() & isInPictureInPictureMode() with `activity` like `getActivity()` in android.

Answer (score 0):

Your Activity must extend **AppCompatActivity** and write code like this

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        if(isInMultiWindowMode && isInPictureInPictureMode){

        }
    }
```

This is not showing any type or error

Comment: i have tried it but no hope the problem is that  isInMultiWindowMode & isInPictureInPictureMode is not recognizing as i mentioned in  my question above

Comment: What Appcompat lib version you are using?

Comment: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1

Comment: Can you update the question with error something like screenshots